# SAS direct dual link connection to an embedded LSI Fusion-MPT controller

Tags: performance, hardware, storage, sas, lsi

This is a hardware question.

I have a dual-link SAS hard drive and a Intel S5000XVNSAS motherboard without the drive cage option. Recently, I bought [a direct dual-link cable in amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003YVP3XG). But when connecting the drive directly using this cable, its performance seems worse, compared to single-link. The controller lists it as two drives in the configuration utility.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get it work 2x times faster, at least when working with the cache. I mean, the drive has two links, and these dual-link direct attach cables, what else can you use them for? Please also suggest literature to consult on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dual-ported SAS disks are not intended for performance, but rather resiliency when used in multipath SAS array configurations *(e.g. external JBOD or SAN situations)*.

For single server or internal storage purposes, there's no benefit or gain achieved by using both ports. If you need better storage performance, please scale with disk count, RAID controller design or move to SSD.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! I think I'll just use software RAID with two identical disks.